# how to send self generated csv attachmnet using action mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, actionmailer

In my Rails application, I have created a CSV file in my booking model.

```
def self.to_excel
  attributes = %w{ name email mobile address transaction_id price deposit paid booked_by date}
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    where('date(created_at) = ?', Date.today).each do |booking|
      csv << attributes.map{ |attr| booking.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```

Booking Controller

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @bookings.to_excel, filename: "Booking-#{Date.today}.csv" }
  end
end
```

Mailer

```
class CsvMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "xyz@gmail.com"
  def send_csv(booking)
     @booking = booking
     attachments['Booking.csv'] = {mime_type: 'text/csv', content: csv}
     mail(to: "xyz@gmail.com", subject:   "Booking Details-#{Date.today}.csv")
  end
end
```

I need to send the auto generated csv file every 24 hours with the details of that days booking. This should just generate the csv and mail it via mailer. How do i proceed. Can any one help.

Comment: ` {mime_type: 'text/csv', content: csv}` how do you get csv in mailer action ?

Comment: @Vishal that is what i was confused how to send the csv. when i did some research on this this is what i found so i added. can u tel how to get the csv to mailer action. What should i give in mailer view

Comment: Please check my answer. let me know if its unclear to you

Comment: @Vishal what should be the query to fetch today's booking, is it something like this  where('date(created_at) = ?', Date.today)

Comment: If you want to fetch all the bookings created today, you can do something like this - `Booking.where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)`

Comment: @Amy Please check  above comment . if the above answer is helpful to you plz accept it

Comment: @Vishal ya sure. It helped me a lot.Thanks for it

Comment: @Amy Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send email every 24 hours, you need to implement cron job.

Please check [gem whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) , its used for cron jobs in rails

In schedule.rb

```
every :day, at: '12:00am' do
  runner "Booking.send_csv"
end
```

In send_csv method , generate CSV file then send it to mail something like below

```
class Booking

  def generate_csv
    bookings = create query for fetching today's bookings
    csv = bookings.to_excel
    CsvMailer.send_csv(user, csv).deliver 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask) for minimal setup. Install gem and initalize file and put this in config/initializers/arask.rb

```
arask.create script: 'Booking.send_csv', cron: '0 0 * * *'
```

And reusing @vishal code:

```
class Booking

  def generate_csv
    bookings = create query for fetching todays bookings
    csv = bookings.to_excel
    CsvMailer.send_csv(user, csv).deliver 
  end

end
```